# "Version string portion was too short or too long" - downloading Python for Windows 10 ARM64

Tags: python, arm64

I'm new to coding and trying to download and install Python on my Windows 10 ARM64 laptop. [This is the guide I'm using.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/developer-tools/python#using-python-on-windows-iot-core-arm64) I'm stuck at step 3, where I get this:

```
C:\Users\Lauri\cpython>pcbuild\build.bat -p ARM64 --no-tkinter
Using py -3.8 (found 3.8 with py.exe)
Fetching external libraries...
bzip2-1.0.6 already exists, skipping.
sqlite-3.33.0.0 already exists, skipping.
xz-5.2.2 already exists, skipping.
zlib-1.2.11 already exists, skipping.
Fetching external binaries...
libffi already exists, skipping.
openssl-bin-1.1.1g already exists, skipping.
Finished.
Using "C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"  (found in the PATH)

C:\Users\Lauri\cpython>"C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"  "C:\Users\Lauri\cpython\PCbuild\pcbuild.proj" /t:Build /m /nologo /v:m /clp:summary /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=ARM64 /p:IncludeExternals=true /p:IncludeCTypes=true /p:IncludeSSL=true /p:IncludeTkinter=false /p:UseTestMarker= /p:GIT="C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe"
C:\Users\Lauri\cpython\PCbuild\python.props(111,31): error MSB4184: The expression "[System.Version]::Parse('')" cannot
 be evaluated. Version string portion was too short or too long. [C:\Users\Lauri\cpython\PCbuild\pythoncore.vcxproj]

C:\Users\Lauri\cpython\PCbuild\python.props(111,31): error MSB4184: The expression "[System.Version]::Parse('')" cannot
 be evaluated. Version string portion was too short or too long. [C:\Users\Lauri\cpython\PCbuild\pythoncore.vcxproj]
```

Here is a screenshot for extra clarity:

[image: here is a screenshot for extra clarity]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I didn't need to create an ARM64 version of Python; 32-bit works as well.